# SplitviewController as a subpage of a NavigationController

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I am trying to have add a splitview as a subpage in UINavigationController hierarchy.  I am guess this is possible, but not sure.  Otherwise, I will just have to do similar functionality manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do that, a UISplitViewController must be the root controller of your app.

From Apple:

> A split view controller must always be
>   the root of any interface you create.
>   In other words, you must always
>   install the view from
>   aUISplitViewController object as the
>   root view of your application’s
>   window. The panes of your split-view
>   interface may then contain navigation
>   controllers, tab bar controllers, or
>   any other type of view controller you
>   need to implement your interface.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/iPadControllers/iPadControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH6-SW2

Comment: I know you can use the splitviewcontroller in other places than the root view controller.  I am just wondering if there is an easier way of doing this.

Comment: Try Matt Gemmell's splitViewController: http://mattgemmell.com/2010/07/31/mgsplitviewcontroller-for-ipad